# How to getText from the element

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using webdriver for forum reply testing.In this scenario,I'm not able to locate and get the reply text ("I want rock!")from following code.

The HTML code is:

```
 <div id="user_ack_con0" class="user_ack_con mt15 clear clearfix"> 
 <dl class="clear clearfix"> 
  <dt>
  <a href="http://www.abc/user/1161/"> 
 </a> 
  </dt>
<div> 
 <a href="[this is not a link](http://www.xxx.com/user/1161/)">Jason</a> 
 <span class="total_icon total_icon5"></span>
  ：I want rock!
</div>
```

I really don't know how to get that text from this element:( Anybody knows,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general solution:

```
def get_text_excluding_children(driver, element):
    return driver.execute_script("""
    return jQuery(arguments[0]).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
    }).text();
    """, element)
```

The element passed to the function can be something obtained from the find_element...() methods (i.e. it can be a WebElement object).

I'm actually using this code in a test suite.

Answer (score 0):

The text is technically inside the div element, so you should try getting it using the find method on the xPath:

```
//div[@id="user_ack_con0"]/dl/div
```

and then getting the text

Comment: Thanks, I used following code:  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='user_ack_con0']/dl/dd/div"))

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#user_ack_con0 > dl > div")).getText()

Or This:

$("#user_ack_con0 > dl > div").textContent

[Jquery get Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ese9h.png)